# issue fetching data from sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a table having two columns - name and symbol. all i want is to get the symbol corresponding to the name. I use this method. It's kind of returning nothing. Please check this out.

```
public String getSymbol(String name) {
    String Symbol = "";
    String[] columns = new String[] { "name", "symbol" };
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().query(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    int iName = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int iSymbol = c.getColumnIndex("symbol");

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

        if (c.getString(iName) == name) {
            Symbol = Symbol + c.getString(iSymbol);
        }

    }
    return Symbol;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function.

```
public String getSymbol(String name)
    {
        try
        {
          String Symbol = "";
          Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, columns, "name = ?" , new String[] {name}, null, null, null);
          if(c.getCount != 0)
          {
               c.moveToFirst();
               Symbol = String.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("symbol"))); 
               c.close();
               return Symbol;
          }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! the code works fine except for this line Symbol = String.valueOf(c.getColumnIndex("symbol")); Actually it should be Symbol = String.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("symbol"))); otherwise it will return the index "1".

Comment: Could you please explain what went wrong in my code. Just to figure out things.

Comment: You are trying to get all the data and then compare with all data. Its not good idea

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **c.getString(iName) == name** while comparing, use **c.getString(iName).equalsIgnoreCase(name)**